# adding fixed tags plus swipe to android studion 1.1

Tags: android, android-studio

In eclipse we can add the "fixed tab + swipe" feature when creating a blank activity. This is not available in the new android studio 1.1 release. Please how I can integrate the fixed tab+swipe feature on android  studio. Thanks